# Can we use fluid designed for wet clutched on a dry clutch DCT?

Tags: ford, transmission-fluid, dual-clutch-transmission

I have a car with Getrag 6DCT250 transmission, which is a DCT with dry clutches. However Ford specified fluid Motorcraft not available in my country.

I have look around for other brand alternatives, nothing exactly meet Ford spec, but the closest is fluid designed for DCT with Wet clutches. Is it okay?

Thanks

Comment: Check with the local Ford importer, I'm sure they have a presence across the world.

Comment: @SteveMatthews Unfortunately, Ford already left my country since 2015. The dealer who continue with after sales service no longer have in stock and dont know when its going to be available again. Only oil from brand 77 lubricant is available and match Ford spec, however i have never heard of the quality of 77 lubricant.

Answer (score 1):

In general you're in a better situation that the reverse; since you have a dry clutch transmission using a "wet clutch" fluid probably won't be harmful - but using a a "dry clutch" fluid will be missing needed additives on a wet clutch transmission.  In any case, I think there are several compatible fluids available ...

Found this on the internet, but I have no way of verifying the veracity:

> I've heard the fluid was originally formulated by Castrol Europe for
>   Ford and was released originally as BOT-341. It was later renamed to
>   Castrol Syntrans FE 75W.

Also, there's a lot of information in this link: [SST special fluids](https://www.evoxforums.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-57355.html)

Amazon lists 4 or 5 compatible fluids for the DPS6 range:

[Genuine Ford Dry Clutch Transmission Fluid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BNVK974)

**Ultimately you best bet is to research or call one of the alternate manufacturers and have them confirm the fluid is compatible.**